# Reproducing Table in Latex,

Tags: multirow

Can Someone give me a help, I would like to reproduce this table in latex (see the picture)
[image: two muppets]

Comment: On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: What specific features do you need, that you don't already know from your previous questions?

Comment: In fact, I know how to create simple table in latex, but here the trick is that i need to create 3 rows, and in the first line there is only one cell. Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please post the code you've got. Somebody can then modify the code to combine the cells in the first row and 2 of the cells in the final row for example, with `\multicolumn{3}{c}{Calcul...}` and `\multicolumn{2}{c}{26.09}`. You have more than 3 rows and I don't understand why that's a problem. You have 3 columns, but what is the difficulty exactly?

Comment: Also, please consider accepting answers to your previous questions. (Have you deleted some of them?)

Comment: Here is my code : 
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}}
  \hline \multicolumn{3}{c}{Calcul de l'épaisseur de la tubulure A,B} \\
 \hline & situation de service & situation d'épreuve
 \hline D$_e (mm)$ & 610 & 610 \\
 \hline f & 204.16 & 318.25 \\
 \hline z & 1 & 1 \\
 \hline P$_{calcul}$(Mpa) & 2.8 & 4 \\
 \hline e^$_{utile}$ & 4.15 & 3.81 \\
 \hline e^$_{nominale}$ & \multicolumn{2}{c}{26.09}
  \hline
\end{tabular}

Comment: Please edit your question to add the code and make it compilable by adding the necessary preamble and `document` environment.

Comment: @cfr: Questions with answers can't be deleted, but I agree with you: The O.P. should accept answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier, erewhon}
\usepackage[table, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline, siunitx}
\newcommand\thickvrule{\color{DarkSeaGreen4}\vrule width 1pt}
\newcommand\thickhrule{\noalign{\setlength\baselineskip{0pt}\color{DarkSeaGreen4} \hrule height 1pt\relax}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
  \centering\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}\arrayrulecolor{DarkSeaGreen4}
  \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}\setlength\fboxrule{1pt}\setlength\doublerulesep{1pt}\doublerulesepcolor{DarkSeaGreen4}
  \fcolorbox{DarkSeaGreen4}{white}{\begin{tabular}{*{2}{c!{\thickvrule}}c}
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\cellcolor{DarkSeaGreen3!60!}Calcul de l’épaisseur de la tubulure A, B}\\ %%
    \thickhrule
    & Situation de service & Situation d’épreuve \\
    \thickhrule
    D\textsubscript{e~mm} & 610 & 610 \\
    \hhline{-|-|-}
    f &204.1666667 & 318.25 \\
    \hhline{-|-|-}
    z & 1 & 1 \\
    \hhline{-|-|-}
    P\textsubscript{calcul} MPa & 2.8 & 4.004 \\
    \hhline{-|-|-}
    \textsubscript{utile} & \cellcolor{gray!40!DarkSeaGreen3!30!} \num{4154370034} & \num{3813309519}\\
    \cline{2-3}
    \hhline{-|-|-}
    \cline{2-3}
    e\textsubscript{nominale} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{26.09}%
    \end{tabular}}
  \caption{The Caption}
  \label{Table:A1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You might find these latex table generators to be helpful:

1. http://www.tablesgenerator.com
2. http://truben.no/table/old/